# apply condition on column1 where string contains only given set of keywords rather contains give set of keywords

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

*how to apply condition on column1 where string **contains only** given set of keywords rather **contains** give set of keywords.* ***Emphasizing on word "only"***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

d = {'_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     'column1': ['FullName', 'custfullnm', 'nm123', 'sitenm', 'full12', 'suplnm', 'countryfulln'],
     'column2': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


key_words = ["full", "nm", "name", "txt", "[0-9]"]

check = f"{'|'.join(key_words)}"

mand_key = "full"

df["column2"] = np.where(
    df.column1.str.contains(mand_key, case=False)
    & (df.column1.str.contains(check, case=False, regex=True)),
    "Full Name",
    "",
)
```

desired output:

```
_id,column1,column2
1,FullName,Full Name
2,custfullnm,
3,nm123,
4,sitenm,
5,full12,Full Name
6,suplnm,
7,countryfullnm,
```

only FullName, full12 matches the criteria  with reason mentioned below:

```
FullName is only made of words from given set of keywords 'full' & 'name'
full12 is only made of words from given set of keywords 'full' & a number '12'
```

And rest doesn't match the criteria because as follows:

```
custfullnm      contains 'cust' not in given list of keywords though contains 'nm' & 'full'
nm123           dones't contain madate keyword 'full' though contains a number & 'nm'
sitename        contains 'site' not in given list of keywords though contains 'name'
suplnm          contains 'supl' not in given list of keywords though contains 'nm'
countryfullnm       contains 'country' not in given list of keywords though contains 'nm' & 'full'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a pattern that will start matching any amount of your allowed subpatterns from the start of the string, then will try to match your mandatory key, and then will again allow any amount of the specified subpatterns till the end of the string:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

d = {'_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     'column1': ['FullName', 'custfullnm', 'nm123', 'sitenm', 'full12', 'suplnm', 'countryfulln', np.NaN],
     'column2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

key_words = ["full", "nm", "name", "txt", "[0-9]"]
mand_key = "full"
check = rf'^(?:{"|".join(key_words)})*{mand_key}(?:{"|".join(key_words)})*$'
df["column2"] = np.where(df["column1"].str.contains(check, case=False, na=True),"Full Name","")
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   _id       column1    column2
0    1      FullName  Full Name
1    2    custfullnm           
2    3         nm123           
3    4        sitenm           
4    5        full12  Full Name
5    6        suplnm           
6    7  countryfulln           
7    8           NaN  Full Name
```

The pattern will look like

```
^(?:full|nm|name|txt|[0-9])*full(?:full|nm|name|txt|[0-9])*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCKeRu/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:full|nm|name|txt|[0-9])*` - 0 or more repetitions of the specified subpatterns
- `full` - mandatory key
- `(?:full|nm|name|txt|[0-9])*` - 0 or more repetitions of the specified subpatterns
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: perfect ! we need to handle exception that if value is "NA" it is considering it as a match. just add an item "NA" and try the same code.

Comment: @Achar007 Add `na=True`, `df["column2"] = np.where(df["column1"].str.contains(check, case=False, na=True),"Full Name","")`

Comment: Hi, I've added I/P and O/P in you answer after I included na=True as per your suggestion

Comment: @Achar007 And it works. All those entries equal to `np.NaN` in `column1`, have `Full Name` in the resulting `column2`. See the updated demo.

Comment: but `np.NaN` is not in our regex pattern right but then why it has to update `column2`

Comment: @Achar007 If the value is `np.NaN` in `column1`, we tell pandas to return `True` using `na=True`, thus, the *then* part is triggered, i.e. the `Full Name` is returned. You cannot match `NaN` values with regex. Regex only operates on string types.

Comment: ohh may be because we used 0 or more repetition instead if we use 1 or more `np,NaN` will not considered as regex match. Am I correct ?

Comment: not really value is not np.NaN but value is NA which is a string but it is considering NaN

Comment: @Achar007 Then just add it to the pattern, `mand_key = "(?:full|NA)"`

Comment: no you understood the other way I do not want to match NA values and update column2 so na=False will do.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer myself:

```
key_words = ["full", "nm", "name", "txt", "[0-9]"]
check = f"{'|'.join(key_words)}"
mand_key = "full"
df["column2"] = np.where(
    df.column1.str.contains(mand_key, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    & df.column1.str.match(check, flags=re.IGNORECASE),"Full Name","",)
df
```

Comment: but still this is not working for column1 value "fullphotourl"

Comment: It is because `'|'.join(key_words)` just matches any one occurrence of any alternative, and `match` requires the match to appear at the start of the string, but does not require a full string match. So, you match all entries that contain `mand_key` anywhere and where the is a subpattern from `key_words` at the start of the string

Comment: you are right , I got to know this only after I ran my code on a bigger dataset.